# how can return return a List or ArrayList by Ajax call

Tags: java, jquery, ajax, struts2

I am trying to get a list of data from an action by ajax call,
I am writing code related to this question:

this is ajax calling code

```
$.ajax({
             type : "POST",
             url : "getwonchartforValue?fromdate="+fromdate+"&todate="+todate,
             data : fromdate,
             dataType : "json",
             success : function(result) {
alert(result);
}
```

here is struts.xml code:

```
    <action name="getwonchartforValue" class="Actions.CrmChartAction" method="getwonchartforValue">
        <result name="success"  type="json">
        </result>
    </action>
```

and in action Class method is:

```html
private List<WonDealChartDto> wonDataList;
public List<WonDealChartDto> getWonDataList() {
    return wonDataList;
}

public void setWonDataList(List<WonDealChartDto> wonDataList) {
    this.wonDataList = wonDataList;
}

public String getwonchartforValue(){


        DaoFactory dfact= new DaoFactory();
        EmailmarketingDao edao=dfact.createEmailMarketingMasterManager();
        HttpServletRequest request=ServletActionContext.getRequest();
        String fromdate=request.getParameter("fromdate");
        String todate=request.getParameter("todate");
        HttpSession session= request.getSession();

        Session hbSession=null;
        try{
            hbSession=HibernateUtilROY.getSession();
            String userid= (String)session.getAttribute("userid");
            String name= (String)session.getAttribute("name");
            String status="Won";
            wonDataList=edao.getDeatailsWonValue(fromdate, todate, userid, name, status, hbSession);




        }
        catch(Exception e){}



        return SUCCESS;
    }
```

I want to get wonDataList(List of data present in this list) in ajax success.
where WonDealChartDto is a bean class I Posted  it here:

```
package dTO;

public class WonDealChartDto {


    private String noOfdeal;
    private String user;
    private String value;

    private String dealHeader;
    public String getNoOfdeal() {
        return noOfdeal;
    }
    public void setNoOfdeal(String noOfdeal) {
        this.noOfdeal = noOfdeal;
    }
    public String getUser() {
        return user;
    }
    public void setUser(String user) {
        this.user = user;
    }

    public String getValue() {
        return value;
    }
    public void setValue(String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public String getDealHeader() {
        return dealHeader;
    }
    public void setDealHeader(String dealHeader) {
        this.dealHeader = dealHeader;
    }
    public WonDealChartDto() {
        super();
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }
    public WonDealChartDto(String noOfdeal, String user, String value, String dealHeader) {
        super();
        this.noOfdeal = noOfdeal;
        this.user = user;
        this.value = value;
        this.dealHeader = dealHeader;
    }



}
```

how can I solve this problem?

Comment: You need to create a REST endpoint or Servlet and write the JSON data to the http response.

Comment: [This](https://struts.apache.org/plugins/json/) might help.

Comment: For the first time i was created json data in a string but in ajax success i got null value for that string.

Comment: What is not working exactly? Rename `getwonchartforValue` to something not starting from `get`.